# excel VBA print row based on date value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to print a report from a sheet called Patrol based on the date of the data.

Range A1 contains different dates but I only want to print the data in rows with first row = to (date + 1) ie tomorrows date.(To print delivery details for the next day)

For each row there is date and 16 other cells. The code below is only printing the table headers

```
Private Sub Comprintpatrol_Click()

    Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Format(Date + 1, Range("A2").NumberFormatLocal)
    ActiveSheet.PrintOut
    ' or
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.PrintOut
    Range("A1").AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Gerry, Did not look at the rest, but should that "date" + 1 not need to be: today()+1   ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're off in saying "Range A1 contains different dates".  I think you mean "Column A contains different dates".  (Range A1 is a single cell, the upper-left cell on the sheet)

You can get column a from the Range function by passing the string "A:A": `Range("A:A")`

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the `UsedRange` instead of `CurrentRegion`. The latter can be tricky because it depends a lot on how your data are set (especially if you have empty cells).

Something like:

```
Private Sub Comprintpatrol_Click()
    Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Format(Date + 1, Range("A2").NumberFormatLocal)
    ActiveSheet.PrintOut
    ' or
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.PrintOut
    Range("A1").AutoFilter
End Sub
```